# Passing a message from one inner class to another inner class.

Tags: java, message, inner-classes

I'm having some problems with passing a message from one inner class to another inner class in an application I'm writing.

```
    public class MealButtonListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
        int selectedRow = theFoodTable.getSelectedRow();
        Food theTempFood = FoodTableUI.this.theFoodCntl.getCurrentFood(selectedRow);
        theMealList.add(theTempFood);
        MealPlannerPopupUI thePopup = new MealPlannerPopupUI(theFoodCntl);
        if(endMeal == true){
            FoodTableUI.this.setVisible(false);
            FoodTableUI.this.theFoodCntl.getMealPlannerUI(theMealList); 
        }
    }
}

     public class NoButtonListener implements ActionListener{
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){  
        MealPlannerPopupUI.this.setVisible(false);
        //MealPlannerPopupUI.this.theFoodCntl.getMealPlannerUI();
        //
    }
}
```

Pasted above are the two relevant classes. I need to be able to pass a boolean from `NoButtonListener` over to `MealButtonListener`. `MealButtonListener` is located in a class called `FoodTableUI` and `NoButtonListener` is located in a class called `MealPlannerPopupUI`. I'm not sure how to get a message between these two inner classes.

Comment: The sender is going to need a reference to the object it wants to send to. There's a few ways to do this. For example, if the instance of MealButtonListener exists when you construct your NoButtonListener you can pass a reference to the object to it then. Without the containing context it's hard to say what the "best way" is to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, listener classes should have *no* data members, public or private, and no need to communicate with each other. Any state should be held by the enclosing class, not the listener class.

Some people feel that listener class methods should do nothing but call an enclosing class method, which actually does all the work. I'm on the fence about this. But if you find yourself having to call some method from the listener yourself, then you should *definitely* move that method's "meat" to the enclosing class.